# Firestore document update using REST api

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to increment one value in firebase store using rest api following this guide https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/commit

I'm trying to make the request using the form given at this documentation.

Here's my path to the document

```
/hindiscript-likes/kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh
```

where `hindiscript-likes` is the collection name.

The document looks like below
[image]

Here's my request body

```
{
  "writes": [
    {
      "transform": {
        "document": "projects/public-api-07/databases/(default)/documents/kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh",
        "fieldTransforms": [
          {
            "increment": {
              "integerValue": 1
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

But upon executing this, it is returnng 400 with the following error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Document name \"projects/public-api-07/databases/(default)/documents/kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh\" lacks \"/\" at index 73.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

Can somebody help ?

Comment: It would be helpful if you edit the question to explain more fully how you are making this request, including the endpoint URL and method you're invoking, and even the documentation you're using that suggests the payload is correct (the error message says specifically that it is not correct).

Comment: Your question should also be clear which document in which collection you are trying to update.  Showing a picture of it in the console might help.

Comment: Add more details.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the name of the collection in the path of the document to update.  What you have now is asking for just "kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh", which it assumes is the name of a collection but a missing document ID. But what you want instead is "hindiscript-likes/kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh".

Try:

```
"document": "projects/public-api-07/databases/(default)/documents/hindiscript-likes/kof97lbQ1IuuvgCHBfOh",
```